# My page only works in Opera!

Tags: cross-browser, html

So I have my web page, http://vercas.webuda.com, which works only on Opera, at least for all my computers and my friend's. Well, more precisely, the CSS and JS only work on Opera. Other browsers see the standard HTML tags style.

Can anybody help me, please?
You may see the source with any browser... And I can also send someone the files via email.

One more thing, please tell me if this is not the right place to post.

Edit: Here are the screenshots:
[image: Internet Explorer View]
[image: Opera View]

Comment: i think anyone here could help you, but you should be more specific... "my web page works only on Opera" is a very broad problem... what do you expect to see? can you post screenshots of expected results vs. real results?

Comment: Oh, yes. The CSS and Javascripts work only on Opera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use header javascript and styles like;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js url"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css url" ></link>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your page is not valid XHTML. The script at the very bottom should be part of the body. Use an XHTML validator and you'll get something that should work out better. In the end do not code the pages by hand yourself, use some framework, like Ruby on Rails or CakePHP this will leave you time to focus on the content not on loose time on formatting/programming quirks...

Comment: Thanks, I use that validator already but the two fu***ng scripts at the end are added by my host. What can I do about them?

Comment: And about the frameworks... I have a free host and I can do the HTML myself. Plus, I have PHP and MySQL so I can make it more fluid. I'd love to use ASP.NET, but hey, nothing's free...